# what is the project root in xcode exactly

Tags: xcode

I have been trying to follow a few tutorials and I keep finding myself in trouble with "locate your project root directory of your xcode project"

If I have created a project called "xxx" in Xcode and I then go to "Finder" and I locate the folder called "xxx". Is this the root of my project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Xcode select the blue project file (top left) in the navigation bar.

In the Identity and Type Inspector <kbd>⌥⌘1</kbd> on the right click on the little arrow after the `Full Path` below `Location`.

A Finder window will open, that's the project root directory

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, this is your project folder. This is where all the files are & should be located that you use in your project.

Hope that helps :)